# Prism region not changing in content region - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism, contentcontrol

I'm attempting to learn Prism and utilize in in a new application I'm working on but am stuck at trying to get it to switch content in navigation. For reference, the video that I was working/learning from was Brian Lagunas' video MVVM Made Simple on YouTube (I've gone through the section multiple times but can't figure out what I'm doing incorrectly). Here is the code behind for my main window (when I added the `regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion()` line it allowed the first view registered to show upon launch but still will not allow me to switch from one view to the other.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    protected RegionManager regionManager = new RegionManager();

    public MainWindow()
    { 
        InitializeComponent();

        regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("Content", typeof(Index));
        regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("Content", typeof(Home));

        DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel(this, regionManager);
```

This is all the code and the prism xmlns statements (these are at the top of all of my views) that I have related to the region/region manager - I've tested the Command binding on the button and know that the method is being triggered so the buttons should be good - but everything else I'm unsure of but per the video it looks correct to me.

**XMLNS statements**

```
xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
```

**Content region in XAML**

```
<!-- Page Content -->
<Border Grid.Row="3" Padding="{Binding WindowContentPadding}">
    <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="Content" />
</Border>
```

**Bootstrapper**

```
class Bootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
{
    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        return Container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
    }

    protected override void InitializeShell()
    {
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
    }

    protected override void ConfigureContainer()
    {
        base.ConfigureContainer();

        // Registering Unity containers for view model navigation
        // All views must be registered.
        Container.RegisterType(typeof(object), typeof(Home), "Home");
        Container.RegisterType(typeof(object), typeof(Index), "Index");

    }
}
```

**MainWindowViewModel**

```
public DelegateCommand<string> NavigateCommand { get; set; }

public MainWindowViewModel(Window _window, RegionManager _regionManager)
{
    window = _window;

    // MVVM model locator code
    regionManager = _regionManager;

    NavigateCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(Navigate);
}

private void Navigate(string uri)
{
    //Test
    Console.WriteLine(uri);
    regionManager.RequestNavigate("Content", uri);
}
```

I've also checked his MVVM Pluralsight course and the instructions look the same there as well so from what I can tell so it must be something I am missing.

Comment: What exactly is your problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> protected RegionManager regionManager = new RegionManager();
> ```

Neither do you want to create your own `RegionManager` nor do you want to do it within a view.

Perform your navigation within the view model and have the region manager injected.

> ```
> public MainWindowViewModel(Window _window, RegionManager _regionManager)
> ```

You don't want to have the view inside the view model and you don't need it anyway.

Have the view interact with the view model through bindings only.

> I have two views (viewA and viewB) and two buttons that should switch between the two views

Then make one button execute `_regionManager.RequestNavigate( "Content", "viewA" )` and the other one `_regionManager.RequestNavigate( "Content", "viewB" )`. The views should be registered like this `_container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<viewA>( "viewA" )`.

You do not want to use `RegisterViewWithRegion` here, just navigate to `ViewA` when your app is done initializing.

Comment: Thanks for that. I switched to injecting the region manager in into the view model and handling the adding the views to the region like this and crossed my fingers but no luck.

        `public MainWindowViewModel(IRegionManager _regionManager)
        {
            // MVVM model locator code
            regionManager = _regionManager;

            regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("Content", typeof(Index));
            regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("Content", typeof(Home));`

Comment: I also have this code that I was executing through the view model constructor that I'm not sure how to get to work no but I can look that up.

`MinimizeProgramCommand = new RelayCommand(() => window.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized)`.

Comment: Well, you don't want to use the view from your view model, as said above. To provide more concrete help, you need to formulate a more concrete problem. What is your exception? What do you want your code to do? What does is do?

Comment: The problem that I'm trying to solve is that I have two views (viewA and viewB) and two buttons that should switch between the two views. ViewA shows upon launch because of the `regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion()` code but the view is not switching when the other button is clicked. I have verified that the code is being accessed when the button is clicked so it is getting to the command but when I click the viewB button, viewB doesn't show. I have verified that viewB works on its own by manually assigning it but can't get the navigation to work in Prism.

Comment: I removed the `RegisterViewWithRegion` code and updated the `RegisterTypeForNavigation<viewA>( "viewA")` code replacing the previous code in the bootstrapper class and launched the application but got no views. Should the `RegisterTypeForNavigation` code appear in the bootstrapper (as shown in my initial post) or should that occur in the main window view model or does it matter? By the way, thank you for your help - I know this is a very vague type problem as it involves so many interconnecting pieces and really appreciate your assistance.

Comment: As with all DI, there should be one point where you do all the mapping. In case of a prism app, this point is the bootstrapper and the modules' initializers.